# How to properly write cloud functions that automatically update firestore documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a firebase cloud function that runs a simple while loop every time a new user creates an account. For some reason, the update function only runs once and stops. The code i use is pasted below

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();
var data;
var counter = 0;


 exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore.document('testCollection/{docID}').onCreate(async(snapshot, context) =>{
   data = snapshot.data();
   while (counter < 5) {
    setInterval(updateCounter(counter), 5000);
  }
  
 })

 async function updateCounter(counter){
  await firestore.collection('testCollection').doc(data['username']).update({
    counter: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  });
  counter++;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using setInterval inside your loop?

Comment: i want the "updateCounter" function to run after a set time for 5 times

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions stops running your code when it hits the final `}` of your function, as otherwise it'd be billing your indefinitely for it.

If you want your code to continue running, you'll need to return a promise that resolves when your code is done with its work (up to 9 minutes).

```
exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore.document('testCollection/{docID}').onCreate(async(snapshot, context) =>{
  data = snapshot.data();
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    while (counter < 5) {
      setInterval(updateCounter(counter), 5000);
    }
    setInterval(() => {
      if (counter >= 5) {
        resolve()
      }
    }, 5000)
  })
})
```

Note that the `while (counter < 5)` loop in the code still won't do what you expect it to do, but at least now the function will continue to run for a few moments and the counter will be incremented.

---

This is probably what you want:

```
exports.onUserCreate = functions.firestore.document('testCollection/{docID}').onCreate(async(snapshot, context) =>{
  data = snapshot.data();
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(updateCounter,  5000);
    setTimeout(updateCounter, 10000);
    setTimeout(updateCounter, 15000);
    setTimeout(updateCounter, 20000);
    setTimeout(updateCounter, 25000);
    setInterval(() => {
      if (counter >= 5) {
        resolve()
      }
    }, 5000)
  })
})
```

This calls `updateCounter` 5 times, each 5 seconds after the previous call. There is a chance that the final database update won't be completed before the call to `resolve`, so I strongly recommend learning more about asynchronous behavior by reading the documentation on [sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and watching Doug's excellent [promises and async behavior in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA) series.

Answer (score 0):

if the requirement is to run this function 5 times, once every 5 seconds, this could work.

```js
for (let i =0;i<5;i++){
  await updateCounter();
  await sleep (5000);
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```